# Finding the probability that a sequence of sums of random variables never passes a certain value?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, generating-functions

Let $S_n = W_1 + ... + W_n$, where all $W_j$ are independent and identically distributed. Let $P(W_j=1)= 0.75$ and $P(W_j=2) = 0.25$. We wish to compute $P(S_n = 5)$ for all possible $n$ and find the probability that the sequence $\{ S_n \}_n$ never reaches the value "5".

Looking at this initially, it feels like the desired probability must be zero. Since it's clear that $n \le S_n \le 2n$, as soon as we reach $n=5$, the probability that $\{ S_n \}_n$ never passes the value of 5 must be $0$. Or am I missing something?

To get the $P(S_n = 5)$, I found what should be the generating function of $S_n$:

$g_{S_n}(s) = (0.75s + 0.25s^2)^n$

from $E(s^{S_n})= (E(s^W))^n$

Then applied the relation: $$P(S_n = 5) = \frac{{g_{S_n}}^{(k)}(0)}{k!} =  \frac{{(0.75s + 0.25s^2)^n}^{(k)}(0)}{k!}$$

This gave me a big expansion:

$$ \frac{(n-4)(n-3)(n-2)(n-1)n(0.75^5)+5(n-3)(n-2)(n-1)n(0.75)^3 +2.8125(n-2)(n-1)n}{5!} $$

Does this seem reasonable? I'm pessimistic about this result, since the above gives a probability bigger than one when we let $n$ be five. Thank you for your ideas/input!

Comment: Notice that $S_n \geq n$. Hence the probability is 0 for $n>5$. It is also 0 for $n=1,2$. It is not hard to write down the probability for $n=3,4,5$. For example, for $n=5$ the probability is $(0.75)^{5}$.

Comment: My guess: The second part of the question means the situation that the sequence $S_n$ reach $4$ and then the new $W_{n+1} = 2$ which makes $S_{n+1} = 6$, jump over $5$ thus never reaches $5$.